# Select count based on condition teradata

Tags: count, teradata

I want to select the number of ads which have at least 1 pageview in a month.

```
SELECT month, count(ads) as total_ads, count(????) as viewed_ads
....
GROUP BY 1
```

I am quite sure it has to be something with a qualify statement but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: No Qualify, basic `HAVING viewed_ads >= 1`, but you can get zero only when you `count(nullableColumn)`.

Comment: I tried that already, but is there a way to work around the "zero only"?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what you actually do